# Как включить сохранение истории в SSH-соединениях?

Tags: linux, shell, history

Есть несколько удалённых машин, с которыми работаю через SSH. На некоторых из них история команд (`history`) сохраняется между сессиями, на других — нет.

Хочу включить сохранение истории на всех. Искал нужную строку в конфигах, сравнил  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` и  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` — они идентичны на тех и других.

Как настроить сохранение истории ssh сессий? Ну и заодно, как при необходимости удалить эту историю вручную?

---

Shell на всех машинах используется одинаковый:

```
user@server:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14122 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

В обоих случаях в `.bashrc` такие строки:

```
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Comment: ssh историю _обычно_ не ведет, ее ведет shell. посмотри какие там шеллы пользователей. Хотя может и от ssh чего то добиться можно, хотя это скорее логи будут, воспользоваться ими будет нельзя. Так что если надо пользоваться - то только средствами шелл

Comment: @Mike: уточнил про шеллы. Что там смотреть нужно?

Comment: для начала посмотреть какой стоит в /etc/passwd. Далее хз. какие то шеллы может вообще писать не умеют. файлы куда пишут отличаются. баш в .bash_history пишет, другие может просто .hystory

Comment: @Mike: разобрался, дело было в правах на `.bash_history`. Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Решение

Нашёл, в чём была проблема. Везде был bash, который писал историю в .bash_history. Однако кое-где сам файл .bash_history принадлежал руту:

```
user@server:~$ ls -hal .bash_history
-rw------- 1 root root 8.2K Nov 20 09:33 .bash_history
```

Вернул права пользователю, сохранение истории заработало:

```
cd ~
sudo chown user:user -R .
```

До сих пор не понимаю, где сохранялась история на время каждой сессии SSH — команда `history` успешно показывала историю текущей сессии.

#### Как настроить

Если .bash_history принадлежит текущему пользователю, то сохранять историю можно. Переключать между «добавлять» и «стирать и переписывать» можно вот этой строчкой в `.bashrc`:

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
```

#### Как удалить

Простой способ: `history -c` (спасибо donRumata за подсказку).
Также можно вручную  почистить `.bash_history` или другой файл `.history`, соответствующий используемому шеллу.

Comment: Удалить историю можно ещё через history -c

Comment: баш не пишет на диск историю постоянно. history видимо его встроенная команда и он историю из памяти показывает. Когда шелл завершается (перехватывает SIGTERM) он сбрасывает историю на диск.

Comment: @donRumata: спасибо, добавлю.